# Entity Framework 5 - How to change connection string for unit testing?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, entity-framework-5, ioc-container

This is my first foray into Entity Framework, and I have a working project with EF5 and the repository pattern. I want to do integration testing against a live DB. I made a snapshot of my existing production database and wrote a stored procedure to recreate a fresh snapshot every time I want to run tests. My question is how to I switch my context to this database snapshot when "in unit testing mode"? In my app.config I have both my live and test connection strings as such:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ReportingDbContext" connectionString="Server=LiveServer;Database=UnifiedReporting;User Id='myuser';Password='mypass';Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="TestingDbContext" connectionString="Server=LiveServer;Database=UnifiedReportingSnapshot;User Id='myuser';Password='mypass';Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

As it stands now, I have my DbContext with the entities I want to use as follows:

```
public class ReportingDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ReportingDbContext() : base("name=ReportingDbContext") // as per my app.config
    {

    }

    // inventory
    public DbSet<ComputerEntity> Computers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NetworkAdapterEntity> NetworkAdapters { get; set; }
    // ... plus a whole bunch more
}
```

What I think I need to do is change the base("name=ReportingDbContext") into ("name=TestingDbContext"), but given how I have my Repository/UnitOfWork setup I'm not seeing how I can do so. The issue may be here in my UnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();

    // inventory
    IRepository<ComputerEntity> Computers { get; }
    IRepository<NetworkAdapterEntity> NetworkAdapters { get; }
    // ... plus a bunch more
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ReportingDbContext _dbContext = null;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _dbContext = new ReportingDbContext();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Inventory
    public IRepository<ComputerEntity> Computers {get { return new Repository<ComputerEntity>(_dbContext); }}
    public IRepository<NetworkAdapterEntity> NetworkAdapters { get { return new Repository<NetworkAdapterEntity>(_dbContext); } }
    // ... lots more
}
```

This UnitOfWork has been great is that I can do a bunch of stuff to all my repositories and save it in one shot without having a bunch of contexts floating around to synchronize. It may or may not be relevant to this question, but this is how my UnitOfWork uses the repository. There is only 1 repository class, but it can be fed with any entity type needed:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T GetById(int id);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void Add(T newEntity);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        }
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

 // ... more implementation of the interface, nothing fancy
}
```

The endpoint of where this magic is used is inside my WCF service. This is where I want to actually run through an integration test. A particular method in my service initializes a unit of work and uses that do stuff. The UnitOfWork creates a ReportingDbContext when it is new'd up, and this ReportingDbContext in turn refers to the connection string of "name=ReportingDbContext". After much reading, I think the answer is to use an IoC container like Unity or Ninject (haven't used one before, but I'd like to), and I'm stuck on how to implement IoC in this situation. Here is an example method that I'm using in my WCF service that seems rather hardcoded to the live database connection string:

```
public ComputerDTO GetComputerDetails(string hostname, string client)
{
 // don't worry about the return type, it's defined elsewhere
    using (var uoW = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        var repo = uoW.Computers;
        var computer = repo.Find(x => x.Hostname == hostname && x.CompanyEntity.Name == client).FirstOrDefault();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I'd like to keep my connection strings inside my app.config if at all possible and be able to somehow switch to the testing connection string during the [SetUp] part of my NUnit testing of the methods in my WCF service.

Comment: If you're using a repository pattern, why not just mock the database?

Comment: After reading a bunch of SO questions/answers on EF5, I've read that mocking may not be the best way to go. It is because Linq-to-Entities with a real DB doesn't behave the same as Linq-to-Objects with a fake DB. Things may pass fine with an in memory DbSet, but fail on the real deal.

Comment: I guess it would depend. If your repository hides EF, then if you're *not* testing the repository code itself it doesn't matter. If you're testing your repository code, then you'll probably need a real DB.

Comment: I always use a separate unit test project with its own app.config. The context has the same name in both.

Comment: Gert - if I use a different connection string with the same name in my test project, will firing up my ReportingDbContext from within the test project reference the local app.config?

Comment: @BillSambrone Yes, that's correct. The unit test project will have some sort of startup fixture. In fact, the unit test project is just an application with a configuration of its own.

Comment: Great! I'll test it now. Might be a bit before I get back to you as I just found that my database snapshot is read-only and I want to test some write operations. I'm cloning my production DB and will let you know how it goes. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it if the test goes well?

Comment: @Gert - this works great. I never imagined the local app.config in my test project would be used for the EF connection string. Post an answer and I will accept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I alway s use a separate unit test project with an App.config of its own. The connection string has the same name as in the main app but the database connection is different.

When you run unit test, e.g. from within Visual Studio, in the background a unit test runner is executed that is nothing but a regular application with its own configuration, the app.config.

You can start and dispose contexts for each test. Most unit test frameworks have attributes to mark methods as setup/teardown fixtures that can either run per test fixture or per test. You could initialize an IoC container in a test fixture setup (`[TestFixtureSetUp]` in NUnit) and a context in a test setup (`[SetUp]` in NUnit).

For some scenarios we use scripts to ensure and restore database state, but for most test we start a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) in the test setup and dispose it (without committing) in the test teardown. This conveniently rolls back any changes made in the test, but the database changes made in the tests are for real.

Comment: Thanks Gert! To make sure I understand the TransactionScope correctly, by not committing my changes to the EF Context/Model will not be saved, even if I call .SaveChanges() correct? The database transaction is a whole separate thing and WILL be committed, since the database has no knowledge of the C# TransactionScope, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Everything that happens within the scope of the TS must be committed explicitly by calling `Complete()`. If this method is not called nothing will ever be committed. So this also goes for `SaveChanges` calls.